# DataGrid: Retrieve Values of all Cells in a DataGridRow

Tags: wpf, datagrid

this is something that shouldn't be this complex.
I have a DataGrid (selection mode is for **Cell**).
I'm simply trying to retrieve *all* the Cell values from the selected row.
I'm at the point where I have a DataGridRow.
I searched for code on iterating the DataGridRow, but no luck.

```
            DataGridCell cell = dep as DataGridCell;
            DataGridRow row = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(cell);
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it. This works for when you select by cell.

```
        var DGrid = (sender as DataGrid);
        var h = DGrid.SelectedCells;
        DataGridCellInfo rt = DGrid.SelectedCells[0];
        var f = rt.Item as DataRowView;
        var rowx = f.Row;
        List<object> valz = new List<object>();
        foreach (object item in rowx.ItemArray) valz.Add(item);
```